# Is it proper to call "world in swapna" as srusti?

Tags: terminology, dream, avastha

There are three avasthas for humans: Jagrath, Swapna, and Sushuphi.

In Jagrath avastha, srusthi of Brahma exists and humans experience their karma in the srusthi.

In Swapna avastha also there are experiences in the subtle body. Can I call the world inside a dream srusti? If not, what is the proper word for it?

My thought:

We cannot call the world in a dream as srusti of the dreamer as it is not voluntarily created by the dreamer and I doubt whether it can be called as srusti of Brahma or not.

Comment: Unknowingly you are well aware that dreamers world is not created by dreamer himself. So some Sakthi is creating yhe world thT is Mukhyapra aor  vayu yes ut is shrishti of  ayu

Comment: Why if jiva creates there should be no u wanted or undesired by jiva to happen in his dream because by logic if jiva  is creator of the dream jaisriram its vayu

Answer (score 0):

### Four states of existence

I'll keep my answer from the Advaitic perspective. According to [*Mandukya Upanishad*](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya), there are four states of being:

1. *Waking state* (Jagratha)
2. *Dreaming state* (Swapna)
3. *Deep Sleep* (Sushupti)
4. *Fourth State* (Turya)

### Subject and Object (Atman and Shrusti)

So, as you described, the waking state has its own *shrusti* (experience), the dreaming state has its own, deep sleep is a different one and Turya is different from the rest three.

All experiences have a thing in common - the self and the second thing is the experience (shrusti) that the self experiences. Let's call these as the *subject* and the *object* respectively. The object appears to the subject - the self experiences a shrusti. But after waking up from the dream, the *object* vanishes because the *subject* comes out of it. Similarly, during the waking state, the *shrusti* vanishes when the subject enters the dream and experiences the dream object. Therefore, the without existence of any single one - subject or object, the other one ceases to exist. Hence, the existence of **both** - subject and object are required for the experience to exist, that is why, *Advaita* (oneness) means - subject and object are **not** different, but one is an **appearance** over the other. In other words, the object is that which is **projected** into the subject to exist, like a shadow and the object that casts the shadow isn't different.

### Relation between Shrusti and Atman

Since, anything that isn't projected into the subject (self), does not exist, therefore the shrusti needs the self (subject) to exist. The relation is described as - a necklace, bangle, and a ring are three distinct objects. But **they aren't different** from *gold* that is their nature. Similarly, *Shrusti* (object) **is just the projection** on the self of different attributes and forms, and it isn't different from the *subject* (self).

### Is it proper to call "world in swapna" as srusti?

Yes, it is correct to call the world in a dreaming state (swapna) as srusti, because in the end, it is only a state that isn't different from self, like waking and deep sleep state.
Further, if it were **wrong** to call dreaming state as shrusti, then what if we are already living in a bigger dream already beyond the three states you mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

Jivas (Be it a blade of grass, ant, human, creator Brahma ) not only have to  pass through the phases of shad vikaaras
(Jayate (birth),Asti (existence), etc),
but also have to experience all three avasthaas.

In the waking state , (Jagrat avasta)
a Jiva realtes it's identity with its gross body and senses , and transacts through sense organs .
Jiva in jagrat , termed as vishwan is at vyavaharika level . So law of karma do apply at  this level of  jivas awareness.

In sleep state(swapna) a Jiva is unaware of its gross body and senses, but still can relate to Manas(mind) which is active .Termed as Taijasan, the Jiva does not transact.. but experiences (vasana janya vritti). the impressions (like unfulfilled desires, fear etc)  that occurred in jagrat.so the law of karma does not apply here , but pain and pleasure is still felt at this level of awareness.

Tattva bodh (verse 6.2)  by HH Shankara details the sleep state

> svapnāvasthā kā? iti cet। jāgrad-avasthāyāṃ yad dṛṣṭaṃ yac chrutaṃ taj-janita-vāsanayā nidrā-samaye yaḥ prapañcaḥ pratīyate sā svapnāvasthā। sūkṣma-śarīrābhimāny ātmā taijasa ity ucyate

Brihadaaranyaka upanishad  4.3.9 details a similar  dream state experienced by a Jiva at the junction of its  prev. and next life .

Anything that causes  bondage, is understood as Jiva Srishti, which is based on Soha,Moha,Raga,Dwesha et al. Hence be it jagrat or swapna, it is supposedly Jiva Srishti.

Ishwara srishti is always vaue neutral, the Creation of Universe,. Anything ,part of the universe is value neutral,
it's is Jivas notion, that creates all the bias.